# OneDrive Syncing Issues

Tags: windows, onedrive

OneDrive keeps reporting that "5 items couldn't be synced". When I click "View Sync problems", it says that the last sync worked correctly. I've tried syncing and restarting, but it hasn't been very helpful yet. How can I fix this.

Comment: What are the 5 items that couldn't be synced? Normal files like Word documents etc.? Or are they, perhaps, some system/hidden files?

Comment: If you browse through your OneDrive folders, you will see a red X on the folder. This means a file inside was not able to be synced. If you see on an Office document, you typically need to open it manually and re-save it (or sometimes re-save as another file name). This error is occuring because Office online is having difficulty translating the document to be compatible with Office online.

Comment: @BigChris: I couldn't find that out because it says the sync worked correctly when I click on the message